# How to Group by Current day and Count Rows?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Hello I have table "os_txn.pay_link" and inside there are many columns.
What I want to do is that I want to count the row numbers by looking at "merchant_id" column for the current day.
So for example what I am looking for an output is that today one of "merchant_id" has
"8" rows. So I want to know the number of rows of the "merchant_id" column for current day.
I think I should use count(*) in view with select statement but couldnt succeed about syntax. So I am open your suggestions thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, a simple option would be

```
select merchant_id, count(*)
from os_txn.pay_link 
where date_column = trunc(sysdate)
group by merchant_id;
```

presuming that `date_column` contains date only (i.e. for today, 8th of October 2022, that's its value - no hours, minutes or seconds).

If date column contains time component, again - a simple option - would be

```
select merchant_id, count(*)
from os_txn.pay_link
where trunc(date_column) = trunc(sysdate)
group by merchant_id;
```

If there's an index on `date_column`, then such a code wouldn't use it (unless it is a function-based index) so you'd rather modify it to

```
where date_column >= trunc(sysdate)
  and date_column <  trunc(sysdate + 1)
```

---

If that's not it, do post sample data and desired result.

Comment: Hello first of all thank you for your answer. I should indicate that I have insert_date_time column instead of sysdate. I think I express myself a bit wrong. So in that case I should look at  insert_date_time and merchant_id and counting rows, right?

Comment: So what I look for is that, what is the number of rows that merchant_id in the insert_date_time

Comment: I don't think so; you should use INSERT_DATE_TIME instead of DATE_COLUMN (in queries I posted). SYSDATE should be as is if "current day" represents "today".  Or, if I misunderstood what you said, maybe it is just `select merchant_id, trunc(insert_date_time) datum, count(*) from os_txn.pay_link group by merchant_id, trunc(insert_date_time)`. Othewise, please, re-read the last sentence I posted in the answer.